# Codeigniter queries fetching cached results (select query results not updated)

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have an admin panel software. I have a list of items. I delete one from the list and refresh the page to run select query again. But the deleted one reappears there. even though its not visible in phpmyadmin.
Tried to clear cache and refreshed a lot but it's still the same.
Adding new item also similar result. query runs successfully but not updated when select query in codeignighter

**database.php:**

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'admin_tr_user',
    'password' => 'zxxxxxxxz',
    'database' => 'xyz_db',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Select all method in a **model**:

```
function get_apps() {

      $this->db->order_by("date", "desc");
      $query = $this->db->get('apps');


      return $query->result_array();

    }
```

Comment: Do you use a server-side cache?

Comment: @LajosArpad I suppose something like that is happening. Where can I find such an option?

Comment: Depends on your server. I suppose you are using CloudFlare or the like. You will need to check the settings of your server.

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes I'm using cloudflare but this is not served via an api. Codeigniter directly queries the database. I think it's related to mysql or php

Comment: Can you empty Cloudflare's cache and tell me whether the problem still persists?

Comment: It's not cloudflare. Checked it already. And I told you before it's not via an api. the page directly fetch the query result as ab array

Comment: If it's MySQL, then you should be able to find the record by querying.

Comment: in which ENVIRONMENT are you? Why not just setting `'cache_on' => FALSE?` AND are you reloading the result page or use some ajax to update the DOM?

Comment: FIXED IT! It was nginx cache serving static files without running the php script everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here:

It was nginx cache causing this issue. I edited the Nginx config to bypass the cache by default.

in **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
  # Cache bypass. I set the default from 0 to 1
    map $http_cookie $no_cache {
        default 1; 
        ~SESS 1;
        ~wordpress_logged_in 1;
    }
```